# De Moivre's theorem application

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose I am given a complex number 
$$z=\frac{(1+i\cos(x)+\sin(x))^n} {(1-i\cos(x)+\sin(x))^n}$$ and I need it to convert to simpler form 
First of all I know that a complex number is of form $$z'=r(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))$$ so I tried to convert $z$ into it (denominator and numerator separately  )
So it becomes 
$$z=(\frac{i-1\cos(x)+i\sin(x)} {i+\cos(x)+i\sin(x)})^n$$
Now how to change it to polar form? So that I can apply de movires theorem?

Comment: I think you mean De Moivre!

Comment: Could you edit your title?

Comment: Edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $1+\sin(x) + i\cos(x)$ (the conjugate of the denominator) in the numerator and denominator to get

$$\frac{1+i\cos(x) +\sin(x)}{1-i\cos(x) +\sin(x)} = i\cos(x) + \sin(x) = e^{-ix+\pi i/2}$$

so

$$\left(\frac{1+i\cos(x) +\sin(x)}{1-i\cos(x) +\sin(x)}\right)^n = e^{-ixn + \pi i n/2} = \cos(nx - \pi n/2) - i\sin(nx - \pi n/ 2)$$

Answer (score 1):

A way to compute this is to write $1=\cos(0)+i\sin(0)$ and then use the [prosthaphaeresis formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

$$\begin{align}\sin(x)+\sin(y)&=2\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})\\\cos(x)+\cos(y)&=2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})\end{align}$$

This turns the stuff inside the powers in numerator and denominator into polar form and then you can use De Moivre's formula to write numerator and denominator in polar form. Finally the quotient of complex numbers in polar form is easy to compute.